# Display lcudi.canvas from lwuit Form

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have two  classes  in one package one extends lcudi.Canvas and another  extends  lwuit.Form

I create two buttons on my Form

My purpose is  displaying the canvas when one of the buttons is pressed.

In my mind this function should display the canvas .

setFullScreenMode(true);
but it doesn't.

This is the Canvas  Class

```
 [code]



 import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
 import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
 import javax.microedition.rms.*;
import javax.microedition.media.*;
import javax.microedition.media.control.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.microedition.rms.*;
public class MainCanvas extends Canvas implements Runnable {

HelloLWUITMidlet  mid;
int screen_width;
int screen_height;
int mode;
int selected;
String current_time;
int[] time_numbers;
long current_time_milli;
long start_timestamp;
int selected_preset;
static String s;
Random generator;

final static int MODE_SETUP = 0;
final static int MODE_RUNNING = 1;
final static int MODE_RINGING = 2;
final static int MODE_PRESETS_TYPE = 3;
final static int MODE_PRESETS_MODE = 4;

public MainCanvas(HelloLWUITMidlet h) {
    mid =h;
    this.setFullScreenMode(true);
   new Thread(this).start();

    screen_width = this.getWidth();
    screen_height = this.getHeight();

    time_numbers = new int[4];
    setCurrentTime();
    initImages();
    generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mode = MODE_SETUP;
    selected = 0;
}



Image back;
Image numbers;
Image font;

int numberFontWidths[];
int numberFontOffsets[];
int numberFontCodes[];

int fontData[] = new int[]
{
    0, 0, 0, 0, 4,
    0, 0, 4, 16, 3,
    4, 0, 4, 16, 4,
    8, 0, 10, 16, 10,
    18, 0, 7, 16, 7,
    25, 0, 9, 16, 9,
    34, 0, 9, 16, 8,
    43, 0, 2, 16, 2,
    45, 0, 4, 16, 4,
    49, 0, 4, 16, 4,
    53, 0, 6, 16, 6,
    59, 0, 11, 16, 10,
    70, 0, 3, 16, 3,
    73, 0, 5, 16, 5,
    78, 0, 3, 16, 3,
    81, 0, 5, 16, 4,
    86, 0, 8, 16, 8,
    94, 0, 4, 16, 4,
    98, 0, 7, 16, 6,
    105, 0, 7, 16, 7,
    112, 0, 8, 16, 8,
    120, 0, 7, 16, 6,
    127, 0, 7, 16, 7,
    134, 0, 6, 16, 6,
    140, 0, 7, 16, 7,
    147, 0, 7, 16, 7,
    154, 0, 3, 16, 3,
    157, 0, 3, 16, 3,
    160, 0, 11, 16, 10,
    171, 0, 11, 16, 10,
    182, 0, 11, 16, 10,
    193, 0, 6, 16, 6,
    199, 0, 13, 16, 13,
    212, 0, 8, 16, 8,
    220, 0, 8, 16, 8,
    228, 0, 8, 16, 7,
    236, 0, 9, 16, 9,
    245, 0, 6, 16, 6,
    0, 16, 6, 16, 6,
    6, 16, 9, 16, 9,
    15, 16, 10, 16, 9,
    25, 16, 4, 16, 3,
    29, 16, 6, 16, 5,
    35, 16, 8, 16, 8,
    43, 16, 6, 16, 6,
    49, 16, 11, 16, 11,
    60, 16, 10, 16, 9,
    70, 16, 10, 16, 9,
    80, 16, 8, 16, 7,
    88, 16, 10, 16, 9,
    98, 16, 8, 16, 7,
    106, 16, 7, 16, 7,
    113, 16, 6, 16, 6,
    119, 16, 9, 16, 9,
    128, 16, 7, 16, 7,
    135, 16, 12, 16, 11,
    147, 16, 7, 16, 7,
    154, 16, 7, 16, 6,
    161, 16, 7, 16, 6,
    168, 16, 4, 16, 4,
    172, 16, 5, 16, 4,
    177, 16, 4, 16, 4,
    181, 16, 13, 16, 13,
    194, 16, 6, 16, 6,
    200, 16, 6, 16, 6,
    206, 16, 8, 16, 7,
    214, 16, 8, 16, 7,
    222, 16, 6, 16, 6,
    228, 16, 8, 16, 7,
    236, 16, 7, 16, 7,
    243, 16, 4, 16, 4,
    247, 16, 8, 16, 7,
    0, 32, 8, 16, 7,
    8, 32, 3, 16, 3,
    11, 32, 3, 16, 3,
    14, 32, 7, 16, 6,
    21, 32, 3, 16, 3,
    24, 32, 11, 16, 11,
    35, 32, 8, 16, 7,
    43, 32, 7, 16, 7,
    50, 32, 8, 16, 7,
    58, 32, 8, 16, 7,
    66, 32, 5, 16, 4,
    71, 32, 5, 16, 5,
    76, 32, 4, 16, 4,
    80, 32, 7, 16, 7,
    87, 32, 6, 16, 6,
    93, 32, 10, 16, 9,
    103, 32, 6, 16, 6,
    109, 32, 6, 16, 6,
    115, 32, 6, 16, 5,
    121, 32, 6, 16, 6,
    127, 32, 6, 16, 6,
    133, 32, 6, 16, 6,
    139, 32, 11, 16, 10
};

int[] fontCodes = new int[]
{
    0x0020,
    0x0021,
    0x0022,
    0x0023,
    0x0024,
    0x0025,
    0x0026,
    0x0027,
    0x0028,
    0x0029,
    0x002a,
    0x002b,
    0x002c,
    0x002d,
    0x002e,
    0x002f,
    0x0030,
    0x0031,
    0x0032,
    0x0033,
    0x0034,
    0x0035,
    0x0036,
    0x0037,
    0x0038,
    0x0039,
    0x003a,
    0x003b,
    0x003c,
    0x003d,
    0x003e,
    0x003f,
    0x0040,
    0x0041,
    0x0042,
    0x0043,
    0x0044,
    0x0045,
    0x0046,
    0x0047,
    0x0048,
    0x0049,
    0x004a,
    0x004b,
    0x004c,
    0x004d,
    0x004e,
    0x004f,
    0x0050,
    0x0051,
    0x0052,
    0x0053,
    0x0054,
    0x0055,
    0x0056,
    0x0057,
    0x0058,
    0x0059,
    0x005a,
    0x005b,
    0x005c,
    0x005d,
    0x005e,
    0x005f,
    0x0060,
    0x0061,
    0x0062,
    0x0063,
    0x0064,
    0x0065,
    0x0066,
    0x0067,
    0x0068,
    0x0069,
    0x006a,
    0x006b,
    0x006c,
    0x006d,
    0x006e,
    0x006f,
    0x0070,
    0x0071,
    0x0072,
    0x0073,
    0x0074,
    0x0075,
    0x0076,
    0x0077,
    0x0078,
    0x0079,
    0x007a,
    0x007b,
    0x007c,
    0x007d,
    0x007e
};

int[] fontKerning = new int[]
{
    70, 44, -1,
    70, 46, -1,
    76, 86, -1,
    76, 89, -1,
    80, 44, -2,
    80, 46, -2,
    84, 44, -1,
    84, 45, -1,
    84, 46, -1,
    84, 97, -1,
    84, 99, -1,
    84, 101, -1,
    84, 111, -1,
    84, 115, -1,
    86, 44, -1,
    86, 46, -1,
    87, 44, -1,
    87, 46, -1,
    89, 44, -2,
    89, 45, -1,
    89, 46, -2,
    89, 58, -1,
    89, 59, -1,
    89, 97, -1,
    89, 101, -1,
    89, 111, -1,
    114, 44, -1,
    114, 46, -1
};

int[] fontCodeTable;

public void initImages() {
    try{
      //  back = Image.createImage("/numbers.png");
        numbers = Image.createImage("/numbers.png");
        font = Image.createImage("/font.png");
        numberFontWidths = new int[]
        {
            17,10,15,15,18,15,16,15,15,16,8
        };

        int offset = 0;
        numberFontOffsets = new int[numberFontWidths.length];
        for(int i=0;i<numberFontWidths.length;i++) {
            numberFontOffsets[i] = offset;
            offset+=numberFontWidths[i];
        }

        numberFontCodes = new int[256];
        numberFontCodes[(int) "0".charAt(0)] = 0;
        numberFontCodes[(int) "1".charAt(0)] = 1;
        numberFontCodes[(int) "2".charAt(0)] = 2;
        numberFontCodes[(int) "3".charAt(0)] = 3;
        numberFontCodes[(int) "4".charAt(0)] = 4;
        numberFontCodes[(int) "5".charAt(0)] = 5;
        numberFontCodes[(int) "6".charAt(0)] = 6;
        numberFontCodes[(int) "7".charAt(0)] = 7;
        numberFontCodes[(int) "8".charAt(0)] = 8;
        numberFontCodes[(int) "9".charAt(0)] = 9;
        numberFontCodes[(int) ":".charAt(0)] = 10;

        fontCodeTable = new int[256];
        for(int i=0;i<fontCodes.length;i++)
            fontCodeTable[fontCodes[i]] = i;



    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}

public void setCurrentTime() {
    current_time = "";
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        current_time = current_time + Integer.toString(time_numbers[i]);
     if(i==1)
    current_time = current_time + ":";
    }
}

public void run() {


    while(true) {
        update();
        Refresh();
        this.repaint();
        long nexttime = System.currentTimeMillis() +60;
        // set your framerate here
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < nexttime)

            Thread.yield();
    }
}

int blinker;

public void update() {
    switch(mode) {
        case MODE_SETUP:
        case MODE_PRESETS_TYPE:
        case MODE_PRESETS_MODE:
            blinker++;
            break;
        case MODE_RUNNING:
            int left = (int) (current_time_milli - (System.currentTimeMillis() -  start_timestamp));
            if(left<=0) {
                playMidi();
                mode = MODE_RINGING;
            }
            int minutes = left / (60*1000);
            int seconds = (left-minutes*60*1000)/1000;
            String min_string = ""+minutes;
            if(min_string.length()==1)min_string = "0"+min_string;
            String sec_string = ""+seconds;
            if(sec_string.length()==1)sec_string = "0"+sec_string;
            current_time = min_string+":"+sec_string;
            break;
        case MODE_RINGING:
            blinker++;
            shake_x = (generator.nextInt()%5);
            shake_y = (generator.nextInt()%5);
            break;
    }
}



public void keyPressed(int key) {
    if(mode == MODE_SETUP) {
        int number_pressed = -1;
        if(key == KEY_NUM0)
            number_pressed = 0;
        if(key == KEY_NUM1)
            number_pressed = 1;
        if(key == KEY_NUM2)
            number_pressed = 2;
        if(key == KEY_NUM3)
            number_pressed = 3;
        if(key == KEY_NUM4)
            number_pressed = 4;
        if(key == KEY_NUM5)
            number_pressed = 5;
        if(key == KEY_NUM6 & selected != 2)
            number_pressed = 6;
        if(key == KEY_NUM7 & selected != 2)
            number_pressed = 7;
        if(key == KEY_NUM8 & selected != 2)
            number_pressed = 8;
        if(key == KEY_NUM9& selected != 2)
            number_pressed = 9;

        if(number_pressed>-1 & selected < 4) {
            time_numbers[selected] = number_pressed;
            selected++;
        } else {
            int action = getGameAction(key);
            if(action == UP) {
                if(selected<4) {
                    if(selected==2)
                        time_numbers[2] = (time_numbers[2]+1)%6;
                    else
                        time_numbers[selected] = (time_numbers[selected]+1)%10;
                } else {
                    if(selected>4)
                        selected--;
                    else
                        selected=0;
                }
            }
            if(action == DOWN) {
                if(selected<4) {
                    int new_val = time_numbers[selected]-1;
                    if(selected==2) {
                        if(new_val==-1)
                            new_val=5;
                    } else {
                        if(new_val==-1)
                            new_val=9;
                    }
                    time_numbers[selected] = new_val;
                } else {
                    selected++;
                    if(selected>6)
                        selected = 6;
                }
            }
            if(action == FIRE) {
                if(selected<4)
                    selected++;
                else {
                    if(selected==4) {
                        start_timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        int minutes = ((time_numbers[0]*10) + time_numbers[1]);
                        int seconds = ((time_numbers[2]*10) + time_numbers[3])+1;
                        current_time_milli = (minutes * 60 * 1000) + (seconds * 1000);
                        mode = MODE_RUNNING;
                    }
                    if(selected==5) {
                        selected=0;
                        mode = MODE_PRESETS_TYPE;
                    }
                    if(selected==6) {
                        mid.notifyDestroyed();
                    }
                }
            }
            if(action == LEFT & selected>0) {
                selected--;
            }
            if(action == RIGHT & selected<6)
                selected++;

        }
    } else if(mode==MODE_PRESETS_TYPE) {
        int action = getGameAction(key);
        if(action == UP && selected>0)
            selected--;
        if(action == DOWN && selected<2)
            selected++;
        if(action == FIRE) {
            selected_preset = selected;
            selected = 0;
            mode = MODE_PRESETS_MODE;
        }
    } else if(mode==MODE_PRESETS_MODE)
    {
        int action = getGameAction(key);
        if(action == UP && selected>0)
            selected--;
        if(action == DOWN && selected<1)
            selected++;
        if(action == FIRE) {
            int[] presets = new int[]
            {
                0,3,0,0,
                0,4,3,0,
                0,5,3,0,
                0,5,0,0,
                0,6,5,0,
                0,8,0,0,
            };
            int offset = selected * 12 + selected_preset * 4;

            time_numbers[0]=presets[offset++];
            time_numbers[1]=presets[offset++];
            time_numbers[2]=presets[offset++];
            time_numbers[3]=presets[offset++];

            mode = MODE_SETUP;
            selected = 4;
        }
    }

    else {
        int action = getGameAction(key);
        if(action==FIRE)
        {
            mode = MODE_SETUP;
            stopMidi();
        }
    }

    if(mode != MODE_RUNNING)
        setCurrentTime();
}

public void keyReleased(int key) {

}

int shake_x;
int shake_y;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int color = 0xFFFF00;

    if(mode == MODE_RINGING && (blinker%10>5))
        color = 0xFF0000;


    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect( 0, 0,screen_width  ,screen_height );
    Graphics gg  ;
    color = 0x00FF00;
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(0,50,50,0);
   color = 0x000FF;

    g.drawString( s ,40,50, 0);
    int x = (screen_width-128)>>1;
    int y = (screen_height-128)>>1;





    if(mode != MODE_PRESETS_TYPE && mode != MODE_PRESETS_MODE)
        paintNumbersCentered(g);

    switch(mode) {
        case MODE_SETUP:
            y = (screen_height>>1)+10;
            if(selected!=4 | (blinker%20>10)) {
                paintTextCentered(g,"START",y);
            }
            y+=15;
            if(selected!=5 | (blinker%20>10)) {
                paintTextCentered(g,"PRESETS",y);
            }
            y+=15;
            if(selected!=6 | (blinker%20>10)) {
                paintTextCentered(g,"EXIT",y);
            }
            break;
        case MODE_PRESETS_TYPE:
            y = (screen_height>>1)-10;
            if(selected!=0 | (blinker%20>10)) {
                paintTextCentered(g,"Supreme Runny",y);
            }
            y+=20;
            if(selected!=1 | (blinker%20>10)) {
                paintTextCentered(g,"Perfect Plasma",y);
            }
            y+=20;
            if(selected!=2 | (blinker%20>10)) {
                paintTextCentered(g,"Hard Boiled",y);
            }
            break;
        case MODE_PRESETS_MODE:
            y = (screen_height>>1)-15;
            if(selected!=0 | (blinker%20>10)) {
                paintTextCentered(g,"Eggs in cold water",y);
                y+=13;
                paintTextCentered(g,"Start when water is",y);
                y+=13;
                paintTextCentered(g,"boiling",y);

            }
            y = (screen_height>>1)+30;
            if(selected!=1 | (blinker%20>10)) {
                paintTextCentered(g,"Start when putting",y);
                y+=13;
                paintTextCentered(g,"eggs in boiling water",y);
            }
            break;
    }

}

public void paintNumbersCentered(Graphics g) {

    int width = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<current_time.length();i++) {
        int c = (int) current_time.charAt(i);
        width+=numberFontWidths[numberFontCodes[c]];
    }

    int x = (screen_width - width) >>1;
    int y = (screen_height >>1)-15;

    for(int i=0;i<current_time.length();i++) {
        int c = (int) current_time.charAt(i);
        int code = numberFontCodes[c];
        int char_w = numberFontWidths[code];
        int char_off = numberFontOffsets[code];

        int sel = selected;
        if(sel>1)sel++;

        if(sel!=i | (blinker%20>10)) {
            g.setClip(x+shake_x,y+shake_y,char_w,20);
            g.drawImage(numbers,x-char_off+shake_x,y+shake_y,0);
        }
        x+=char_w;
       }

       }
       public void Refresh()

      {

      Date t = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
      s = t.toString();

      }



public void paintTextCentered(Graphics g,String text,int y) {
    int width = 0;
    int textlen = text.length();
    for(int i=0;i<textlen;i++) {
        int code = fontCodeTable[(int)text.charAt(i)];
        int char_width = fontData[code*5+4];
        width+=char_width;
    }

    int x = (screen_width-width)>>1;
    int last_char = -1;

    for(int i=0;i<textlen;i++) {
        int this_char = (int)text.charAt(i);
        int code = fontCodeTable[this_char];
        int offset = code*5;
        int sx = fontData[offset++];
        int sy = fontData[offset++];
        int sw = fontData[offset++];
        int sh = fontData[offset++];
        int aw = fontData[offset++];

        if(i>0) {
            int koff = 0;
            int klen = fontKerning.length / 3;
            for(int k=0;k<klen;k++) {
                koff = k*3;
                if(last_char==fontKerning[koff] && this_char==fontKerning[koff+1]) {
                    x+=fontKerning[koff+2];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(sw>0 && sh>0) {
            g.setClip(x,y,sw,sh);
            g.drawImage(font,x-sx,y-sy,0);
        }
        x+=aw;
        last_char = (int)text.charAt(i);
    }

}

Player player = null;

public void stopMidi() {
    try{
        if(player!=null) {
            player.stop();
            player.deallocate();
        }
        player = null;
        System.gc();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void playMidi() {
    try {
        stopMidi();
        player = Manager.createPlayer(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ring.mid"),"audio/midi");
        player.realize();
        VolumeControl vc = (VolumeControl) player.getControl("VolumeControl");
        vc.setLevel(100);
        player.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

protected void hideNotify() {

}

protected void showNotify() {

}
}
```

[/code]

And that is the Form

```
[code]
import Pes.*;
//import Pes.MainCanvas;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.*;
 import com.sun.lwuit.*;
 import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;
 import com.sun.lwuit.events.*;
   import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.*;
  public class HelloLWUITMidlet extends MIDlet implements ActionListener {
   HelloLWUITMidlet hh;

   public void startApp() {
  com.sun.lwuit.Display.init(this);

   final    com.sun.lwuit.Form f = new com.sun.lwuit.Form( " SOFTWARE SCREENS");

   final   MainCanvas    m = new MainCanvas(hh);
    f.getStyle().setBgColor(0X99CCFF);
   BoxLayout boxlayout =new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);

   com.sun.lwuit.Command exitCommand = new com.sun.lwuit.Command("Exit");
  f.addCommand(exitCommand);
  f.addCommandListener(this);



  final  Button button = new Button("  GOALS  ");
  final  Button button1 = new Button("  TIME SETTING");

   Style btnstyle = button.getSelectedStyle() ;
   Style btnstyle1 = button1.getSelectedStyle() ;
   btnstyle.setBgColor(0X0000FF);
    btnstyle.setFgColor(0XFFFFFF);
  btnstyle1.setBgColor(0X0000FF);
  btnstyle1.setFgColor(0XFFFFFF);
  // button.getStyle().setBgColor(0X99CCFF);

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   private int c = 0;
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    c++;
     // Display.init(m);
     m.setFullScreenMode(true);

          }
       });


     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      private int c = 0;
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
       c++;

      m.setFullScreenMode(true);

        }
            });
         f.addComponent(button1);
           f.addComponent(button);
            f.show();
            }

              public void pauseApp() {}

           public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {}

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               notifyDestroyed();
               }


                 }





   [/code]
```

**Notice :-**  If you need the images and sounds included in my code to test my application  you can download eggtime  application from here 
 http://www.bambalam.se/eggtimer/

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `lwuit` and `javax.microedition` code together.

That is why you need to transfer control from `lwuit` `Display` to `javax.microedition.Display` control. For this you need to call
`javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(hh).setCurrent(m);`
after you call `setFullScreenMode` in your `actionListener`.